# XCode 6 GM missing Swift for Cocoa and Storyboard options

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode6gm

I've just downloaded XCode 6 GM. While in beta 7 I could create Cocoa apps using storyboards, the option is disabled in the GM. Did anyone face similar issues, and if so how did you fix it?

Thanks.

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 6.0 has SDKs for iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.9. Swift for OS X is part of the 10.10 SDK, which is not yet final.

To use Swift for OS X, you need to be on Xcode 6.1, which has the SDK for OS X 10.10 Yosemite. (You need to build with the 10.10 SDK to get Swift even if you're targeting 10.9.) Yosemite is still beta, and so is [Xcode 6.1](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/).

Storyboards for OS X are also a 10.10 feature.